# Update textbox values in Javascript every second

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to translate a pay and savings calculator I made in excel to a web page I can host on my website and access anywhere.

What I want is to have the values automatically update without the need of pressing a load of buttons.

I've done a bit of research and put together this code, but its not working...

```
window.setInterval(function () {
  var week1 = document.getElementsByName("week1").value;
  var week2 = document.getElementsByName("week2").value;
  var week3 = document.getElementsByName("week3").value;
  var week4 = document.getElementsByName("week4").value;
  var week5 = document.getElementsByName("week5").value;

  var weekTotal = week1 + week2 + week3 + week4 + week5;

  document.getElementById("totalHours").innerHTML = weekTotal;
}, 1000);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @LeeTaylor there are two obvious bugs.  Misuse of `getElementsByName`, and getting string concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: @Alnitak - I see that. I was using the **review** system, so didn't see the answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use element IDs, not names - then you can use `document.getElementById()`
2. cache those element variables so you don't have to call `document.getElementById()` every time
3. convert `.value` into a number with `parseInt(s, 10)` - although you haven't said how it fails this *will* be causing you a problem because `.value` is normally a string and using `+` on strings does concatenation, not addition.
4. don't do it in a timer loop - it'll prevent updates from happening in real time.  Instead, use an `onchange` (and/or `oninput`) event handler which will be called immediately whenever any value is updated.  With `onchange` the sum would be calculated each time the user moves from one input to another, with `oninput` it'll recalculate on each key press (or copy/paste, etc).

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/7Gzs6/

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var totalView = document.getElementById('total');

function add(ev) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, n = inputs.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var v = parseInt(inputs[i].value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(v)) {
            total += v;
        }
    }
    totalView.innerHTML = total;
}

form.addEventListener('change', add, false);​
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This should help me finish the rest.

Comment: There is no need to use getElementById at all. The OP can use `var form = document.forms.myform`, and then `form.week1.value` and so on. Form controls must have names to be successful. If they have names, they don't need IDs. Also, not all browsers support the change event for forms. The listener should be on each input that might change.

Comment: Would you recommend caching the elements because getElementByID is an expensive operation, or for stylistic reasons?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye mostly because IMHO one should never repeatedly call a function just to obtain the same result over and over.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye—getElementById isn't particularly expensive, it's just not necessary. It also means the controls must have a name and ID when they can be referenced just as easily by name and therefore don't need an ID.

Comment: @RobG what browsers won't let an `onchange` event bubble to the parent form?  Also, names on form controls are optional, and only required if the form will be submitted to a server.

Comment: @Alnitak - the change event doesn't bubble in various versions of IE at least. The primary purpose of a form is to submit data to the server so it makes sense to use names not IDs so that simple fallback options are available.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array

So you probably want to retrieve the first element `[0]` with name 'week1' and so on.

```
var week1 = document.getElementsByName("week1")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer you've selected, consider making use of the collections available and use property access rather than function calls. e.g.

```
<script>

// Test that v is an integer
function isInt(v) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(v + '');
}

// Update the total if entered value is an integer
function updateTotal(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var value = el.value;

  // If value is an integer, use it
  if (isInt(value)) {
    el.form.total.value = +el.form.total.value + +value;

  // Otherwise, do nothing (or show an error message asking
  // the user to input a valid value)
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

// Add listeners to elements that need them
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.forms['f0'];
  var els = form.elements;
  var re = /^week/;
  var total = 0;

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (re.test(els[i].name)) {
      els[i].onchange = updateTotal;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<form id="f0" action="">
  week1<input name="week1" value="0"><br>
  week2<input name="week2" value="0"><br>
  week3<input name="week3" value="0"><br>
  week4<input name="week4" value="0"><br>
  week5<input name="week5" value="0"><br>
  total<input name="total" value="0" readonly>
  <input type="reset"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

The `isInt` function is a bit simple, it should trim leading and trailing spaces etc. but is sufficient to show that you must test the input before using it in an operation. This is also a great example of where inline listeners are probably a better solution.

Comment: by property access are you talking about `.onchange`?  That's very old school...  In any event (no pun intended) I don't think your answer is correct - it always adds to the total, but never amends the total if a value is changed.

Comment: Regarding property access: I mean direct access to form controls. Regarding the total: yes, you're correct.